# Scroll mouse, keyboard constantly freezing for short time

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Dell XPS15-9560. Graphics card is

```
NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
```

My scroll mouse and keyboard will freeze every several seconds for a couple of seconds and then resume. It's happened a few times while typing this message. When using the scroll mouse the scrolling will freeze and then the page jumps to the new location. This started happening recently.

The /var/log/syslog is full of these errors (nearly every second):

```
Dec 19 14:33:18 xps15-9560 kernel: [234236.432123] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Dec 19 14:33:18 xps15-9560 kernel: [234236.432151] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 19 14:33:18 xps15-9560 kernel: [234236.432161] nvme 0000:04:00.0: device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Dec 19 14:33:18 xps15-9560 kernel: [234236.432172] nvme 0000:04:00.0: [ 0] RxErr
```

Is this an error with the graphics driver or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the usb c hub I was using to drive a second external monitor.  I was using the `UPGROW 8-in-1 Type C Adapter`.  When I swapped it out for the `UtechSmart 6 In 1 USB C to HDMI Adapter with 1000M Ethernet` usb hub the problems with the scroll mouse and keyboard freezing stopped.

The errors shown above continue to occur, however, but apparently those errors are not related to the freezing I was seeing.